# Updating GitLab instructions to use new IP address of server

Tags: gitlab

I installed GitLab on a local server which I use as an internal GitHub. I have set it up with an original IP address of xxx.xxx.xxx.20, and it has since changed to xxx.xxx.xxx.21. However, the instuctions when I create a new project still say `git clone http://xxx.xxx.xxx.20/path/to/project`. I was trying to paste that command and run it but nothing was happening until I realized the IP was the old one. How can I refresh the IP that GitLab think's it's running on so that it shows the new one?

Thanks

Comment: @Rekovni Ahhh yes I forgot about the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file. That fixed it. If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` as per the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab), and then doing a `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` should resolve this issue.